# I am trying to POST comments, working for one second but then they disappear once I click on submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

The comment appear for a second and then it disappears once I post it, without refreshing the page.
Can you please help me?
I would like to append them ( username and comment below) in a div.

This is the code so far:

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
    var comment = $("#comment").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            $("#result").append(comment);
        }
    })
});

<form action="" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Add a comment</legend>
        <label for="user">Username</label>
        <input type="text"  name="user" id="user" value="" maxlength="20">
        <br><br>
        <label for="comment">Comment</label>
        <textarea rows="6" cols="50" name="comment" id="comment"></textarea>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
    </fieldset>
</form> 
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: hey , are they disappearing after you refresh or does it automatically disappear from the view after getting added

Comment: after getting added sorry

Comment: can you try wrapping the comment data in a <p> tag or a suitable tag and appending instead of directly appending the data

Comment: i tried but couldn't find a proper solution, can you please help me with the code?

Comment: sure , is it possible to see the code , uploaded on something like Plunker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that that it works for 1 second and then disappears is that 2 things are happening when the user hits the submit button.

Firstly, your jQuery is triggered which initiates the Ajax request (which you have said is working properly).

Secondly, the default HTML form submit button action is initiated which performs the page refresh in this instance.

You have two ways of tackling this. Firstly, you could change your `<input type="submit">` button to a regular `<button>` so that the regular HTML form submission doesn't occur (but your jQuery will still run). Alternatively, you can call `event.preventDefault();` inside your jQuery click command which will prevent the default HTML form submission from occurring. More info [here](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/).

Comment: I tried to do it but still same problem !! I have changed the input into a button and I tried to use preventDefault()

thanks for the help

Comment: @MatteoSoresini, change `$("#submit").click(function() {` to `$("#submit").click(function(event) {` then add `event.preventDefault();` as the first line within the click function. Also, your `.ajax` url is pointing to `$(this).attr('action'),`. In this instance, I think `$(this)` is your `$("#submit")` button. This button doesn't have an 'action' attribute set, so it will fail. Also, even if you pointed it to the form element's native action attribute, you haven't set one there either, so again it will fail. What is the `.ajax()` call doing? Does it need to be sent to the server at all?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than `$("#result").append(comment);`, try `$("#result").html(comment);`

Comment: it is actually working but the page refresh automatically once i post it and disappear again